# Difference between dplyr::rename and dplyr::rename_all

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have reviewed the documentation for `dplyr` multiple times and it indicates that `dplyr::rename_all` is a "scoped" variant of `dplyr::rename`. Can someone explain what this entails with regard to syntax and functionality? Why use one versus the other? The documentation for `dplyr` is not clear about this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- Use `rename_all` to apply a function on all names
- Use `rename` to give individual replacement names

For example:

```
library(dplyr)
cars %>% rename_all(toupper) %>% head
#   SPEED DIST
# 1     4    2
# 2     4   10
# 3     7    4
# 4     7   22
# 5     8   16
# 6     9   10

cars %>% rename_all(substr, 3) %>% head
#   spe dis
# 1   4   2
# 2   4  10
# 3   7   4
# 4   7  22
# 5   8  16
# 6   9  10

cars %>% rename(speeeeeed = speed, distance = dist) %>% head
#   speeeeeed distance
# 1         4        2
# 2         4       10
# 3         7        4
# 4         7       22
# 5         8       16
# 6         9       10
```

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the cases already mentioned, `rename_all` comes in handy when you have a full set of column name replacements assigned to an existing variable.

The difficulty comes when you try to pass that variable into `rename_all`. Passing the variable directly into the second argument, `.funs`, won't work, with or without the `funs()` wrapper mentioned in dplyr's help file. A variable name is not a function or an expression. It is a symbol.

> .funs  A single expression quoted with funs() or within a quosure, a
>   string naming a function, or a function.

```
new_car_names <- c("a", "b")

# Won't work.
cars %>% rename_all( new_car_names ) %>% head
cars %>% rename_all( funs( new_car_names ) ) %>% head
```

Here are some examples of a "single expression quoted with funs()" that work.

```
cars %>% rename_all( funs( c("a", "b")) ) %>% head

cars %>% rename_all( funs( c(new_car_names) ) ) %>% head

cars %>% rename_all( funs( ~new_car_names ) ) %>% head

cars %>% rename_all( funs( quo(new_car_names) ) ) %>% head
```

Here is an example of a "single expression within a quosure".

```
cars %>% rename_all( quo( quo(new_car_names) ) ) %>% head
```

Here is an example of "a function" (one that does not use its arguments).

```
cars %>% rename_all( function(.){new_car_names} ) %>% head
```

And, finally, an example of "a string naming a function".

```
test_function <- function(.){new_car_names}

cars %>% rename_all( "test_function" ) %>% head
```

While this question does not refer to `rename_at`, these examples inform possible usage. Note that the second argument for `rename_at`, `.vars`, accepts character vectors or position numbers to identify the existing columns, which you would like to rename.

```
cars %>% rename_at( .vars = "speed", function(.){new_car_names[[1]]} )

cars %>% rename_at( .vars = 1, function(.){new_car_names[[1]]} )

cars %>% rename_at( .vars = c(1,2), function(.){new_car_names} )
```

Comment: you'd mostly use `cars %>% setNames(new_car_names)` in these cases though, wouldn't you ?  `cars %>% rename_all( funs( ~new_car_names )) ` doesn't work. Maybe you meant `cars %>% rename_all(~new_car_names)`

Comment: Habit on my part. I've been using the rename family (`rename`, `rename_all`, `rename_at` and `rename_if`) given the range of situation the family addresses and that a search for "rename" finds all in code. `setNames` works, though check out `set_names` from the package `rlang`. It works like `setNames`, but with added features.

Comment: As for `cars %>% rename_all(~new_car_names)` not working, I just tried: `new_car_names <- c("a", "b")` `cars %>% rename_all( funs( ~new_car_names ) ) %>% head` and it worked. Do those two lines fail to execute or do they fail to rename for you?

Comment: @SoFarther I confirm that `new_car_names <- c("a", "b"); cars %>% rename_all( funs( ~new_car_names ) ) %>% head` does not work for me.